# Livewire Upload With Camera Input

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a form that allows users to upload an image on web, however on mobile rather than select the file from file manager I want the user to be able to tap on the input and have it open the camera and upload to the server automatically when the user takes the picture.

My issue is this is not working with Livewire and I can't seem to find the error it just doesn't work.  I can upload the file from web and that works fine however uploading from the camera doesn't.

This is my blade code:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 bg-white p-5">
@foreach($documentTypes as $documentType)
<label class="flex flex-col h-48 items-center justify-center px-5 py-6 bg-white text-blue rounded-lg tracking-wide border-2 border-dashed border-blue @if (!isset($files[$loop->index])) cursor-pointer hover:text-blue-500 @endif">
    @if (isset($files[$loop->index]))
    @if ($files[$loop->index]->extension() == 'png')
    <img src="{{ asset('images/png.png') }}" class="w-16 h-16 object-fit">
    @elseif ($files[$loop->index]->extension() == 'jpeg' || $files[$loop->index]->extension() ==
    'jpg')
    <img src="{{ asset('images/jpg.png') }}" class="w-16 h-16 object-fit">
    @elseif ($files[$loop->index]->extension() == 'pdf')
    <img src="{{ asset('images/pdf.png') }}" class="w-16 h-16 object-fit">
    @endif
    <span class="mt-2 text-center leading-normal">{{ $documentType->name }}</span>
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
        <span class="text-xs text-gray-600 text-center">{{
            $files[$loop->index]->getClientOriginalName() }}</span>
        <a class="bg-transparent border-transparent cursor-pointer" wire:click="removeUpload({{ $loop->index }})"><i class="las la-minus-circle text-red-500 ml-1"></i></a>
    </div>
    @else
    <i class="las la-cloud-upload-alt text-6xl"></i>
    <span class="mt-2 text-base leading-normal">Upload<span wire:loading wire:target="files.{{ $loop->index }}">ing</span> {{ $documentType->name }}</span>
    <input type='file' wire:model="files.{{ $loop->index }}" name="files.{{ $loop->index }}" accept="*" capture class="hidden" />

    @endif
    <div wire:loading wire:target="files.{{ $loop->index }}">
        <img src="{{ url('images/loading.gif') }}" class="w-8 h-8 object-contain" alt="">
    </div>
</label>
@endforeach
```

The specific line for the upload input field is:

```
<input type='file' wire:model="files.{{ $loop->index }}" name="files.{{ $loop->index }}" accept="*" capture class="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the issue was actually my max_file_upload_size, phones take hi -res photos so had to increase that value along with the execution time to get it working on mobile.